# Excel, In need of way to convert one one column of data in to 4 columns

Tags: excel

In need of way to convert one one column of data in to 4 columns  containing Lat Long (mapping) columns the "Lat" will always be a positive number the "Long" always negative number, a date column and a string column. any thoughts ? example of data. "Date" row 1, (String) "description" row 2, "Lat" row 3, "Long" row 4. there can be several ***Lat & Long Pairs*** before the next "description", there are several "descriptions" before the next "Date". These are emergency calls by date then type and then location every date has several call of different types and of course different locations. thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: actual example data please

Comment: Wednesday, January 1 2020
Chest Pain
43
-112
Diabetic Problem
43
-112
The lat and long had to changed as per regulations. but the sample is accruate

Comment: lat number is "43", long number is "-112" on there own separate rows

Answer (score 0):

Follow these directions:

1. Add a new worksheet in the same Excel workbook as your 4500+ lines of data. Label it anything you'd like.
2. Add the following headers to the new worksheet:

   - `A1`: "Date"
   - `B1`: "Description"
   - `C1`: "Lat"
   - `D1`: "Long"
   - `E1`: "Description (2)"
   - `F1`: "Lat (2)"
   - `G2`: "Long (2)"

     > Changing these won't break anything but this will help you understand what is going where for the time being.
3. Assuming the data is on worksheet "Sheet1" (if not, just change "Sheet1" in each of the formulas to the correct worksheet) and that the data is in column A, paste the following formulas:

   - `A2` (Date): `=LEFT(Sheet1!A1,FIND(2020,Sheet1!A1)+3)`
   - `B2` (Description): `=MID(Sheet1!A1,LEN(A2)+2,FIND(C2,Sheet1!A1)-LEN(A2)-3)`
   - `C2` (Lat): `=SUBSTITUTE(MID(Sheet1!A1,FIND(D2,Sheet1!A1)-10,10)," ", "")`
   - `D2` (Long): `=SUBSTITUTE(MID(Sheet1!A1,FIND(" -",Sheet1!A1),FIND(" ",Sheet1!A1,FIND(" -",Sheet1!A1)+1)-FIND(" -",Sheet1!A1))," ", "")`
   - `E2` (Description (2)): `=MID(Sheet1!A1,(FIND(D2,Sheet1!A1)+LEN(D2))+1,FIND(" -",Sheet1!A1,FIND(D2,Sheet1!A1)+LEN(D2))-(FIND(D2,Sheet1!A1)+LEN(D2))-10)`
   - `F2` (Lat (2)): `=SUBSTITUTE(MID(Sheet1!A1,FIND(E2,Sheet1!A1)+LEN(E2),10)," ","")`
   - `G2` (Long (2)): `=MID(Sheet1!A1,FIND(" -",Sheet1!A1,FIND(E2,Sheet1!A1))+1,10)`
4. Select the range `A2:G2` and drag the formulas down 4500+ times.

Your data will now be in a tabular format.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try it see if it works for what I need, I hate thoughts of the 4500+ rows in the column having to separate in to: a date column: :description column: :a Lat column: and Long column. BTW the Lat and long pairs have to match up . meaning the Lat which is, say on A5 its partner would be on A6. those would need end up on say D4 and E4, or where ever long as they stay a pair. oh both lat and long have a decimal and 6 numbers behind them.

Comment: No problem. I am updating my answer now that I have a better understanding of what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you parsing data with both negative lat and long?

Comment: The location I am looking at the Lat will always be positive, the Long will always be negative.

Comment: unfortunately, this solution did not work the Date worked fine but the other cells did not come into new spread sheet. it did give me some other thoughts of how to proceed. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Please consider upvoting the answer!